# Forma correcta de representar las diferentes partes de un pais

Tags: base-de-datos, transact-sql

en mi proyecto tengo requerimiento de guardar las sucursales de cierto negocio, en una calificacion de paises

según mi diseño de base de datos, tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi pregunta es que si es la practica correcta, o debería realizar una división mas profunda, ejemplo con Nicaragua,.

Pais: Nicaragua
Region: Pacifico
Departamento: Managua
Ciudad: Managua

lo que quiero es estandarizar el modelo para cualquier pais del mundo, escucho sus ideas y aportes,

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola si lo que buscas es estandarizar el modelo para cualquier país del mundo entonces esta perfecto el modelo que tienes. Ahora, si profundizas más ya dejaría de ser **estandar** para todos los países. Quizas puedes incorporar como sugerencia el codigo postal. Saludos.

Comment: Entiendo, lo del código postal lo dejare en la parte de la tabla sucursal, y datos de sus coordenadas también, muchas gracias por tu aporte!